# move constructor when returning a "chained" object

Tags: c++

Say I have a class that is move-only, and this class has methods that "chain". example:

```
struct C {
    C() = default;
    C(C const&) = delete;
    C(C&&) = default;

    C& chained() {
        return *this;
    }

    int a;
};

C foo(C c) {
    return c.chained();
}

int main()
{
  auto o = foo(C{});
}
```

I get an error at the return statement of foo: "Use of deleted function 'C::C(const C&)'".

Why is trying to call the copy constructor? Shouldn't it be using the move constructor since its a return statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is trying to call the copy constructor? Shouldn't it be using the move constructor since its a return statement?

No. You are referring to, and misinterpreting, [copy elision](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3) (as pertaining to NRVO). Only when the returned expression is a an *id-expression* (just a name) that refers to an object from the function's parameter list or a local, will a move be attempted first.

You don't return an id-expression, your expression is the result of a call to a member function.

Comment: So can I wrap the return in `std::move()`, or am I forcing the compiler to accept something it was somehow trying to protect me from?

Comment: @baruch - It's less about protecting you and more about being conservative when applying a potentially breaking optimization. If *you know* that reference is to an object that can be moved from, you can apply the move explicitly. The compiler won't do it itself.